# Omniauth Facebook auth + identity using the same model instead of two

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, identity, omniauth

I've setup Omniauth Facebook authentication according to this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/
And now I'm trying to combine it with omniauth-identity using the same User model instead of a separate Identity model as in this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity?view=asciicast , but I cannot get it to work properly.

This is is my  initializers/omniauth.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx'
  provider :identity, :fields => [:email], :model => User
end
```

I've added 'password_digest' column that is needed by omniauth-identity to my User model/table and changed the User model code

from

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorizations
  #validates :name, :email, :presence => true

  def add_provider(auth_hash)
    # check if the provider already exists, so we don't add it twice
    unless authorizations.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"], auth_hash["uid"])
      Authorization.create :user => self, :provider => auth_hash["provider"], :uid => auth_hash["uid"], :token => auth_hash["token"]
    end
  end
end
```

to

```
class User < OmniAuth::Identity::Models::ActiveRecord
  ...
end
```

but when I do that the code in the Authorization model that creates the User and the Authorization models does not work properly
When the User model extends from ActiveRecord::Base the records are created just fine but when I extend the user model from OmniAuth::Identity::Models::ActiveRecord the user model is not stored in the database when you create a new authorization.

This is the Authorization model code:

```
class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :provider, :uid, :presence => true

  def self.find_or_create(auth_hash)
    unless auth = find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"], auth_hash["uid"])
      user = User.create :name => auth_hash["info"]["name"], :email => auth_hash["info"]["email"]
      auth = create :user => user, :provider => auth_hash["provider"], :uid => auth_hash["uid"], :token => auth_hash["credentials"]["token"]
    end

    auth
  end
end
```

When I extend the User model from ActiveRecord::Base and try to create a new registration with Identity I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError
unknown attribute: password
```

Is there any way to get this working this way? I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 3):

not sure you're still having the problem, but maybe someone on the interwebz will.

I just posted a solution on by blog, should solve your problems:

http://bernardi.me/2012/09/using-multiple-omniauth-providers-with-omniauth-identity-on-the-main-user-model/

Comment: Do you have a github repository showing the files from your tutorial in context? I can't figure out if they're supposed to be integrated into files from a RailsCast or if they're just meant to stand alone. For instance, new.html.erb ... where does that go? Sorry if these are noob-ish concerns but I could use some clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to add attr_accessor :password  and may be attr_accessor :email